I cant get my simple router to work properly
Imagine of Topology, Controller and my terminalsSo im currently trying to setup a simple router that blocks traffic from a specific IP, but allows other connections to travel freely. The picture shows my code from my controller and the other is the topology for my connections. Please help me!!
I am trying to get h1 h2 h3 and h5 to connect with eachother, (see terminal on right side "h1 ping h2") while also making sure that "h2 ping h4" get blocked.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Your image of text isn't very helpful.  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

When I look at the code you have in the screenshot, I see you defined method do_final(), and inside you have the logic to detect if the IP is the blocked IP, if so you want to drop the packet and if not then you will forward the packet and there's a comment saying:
#Implement forwarding logic here based on the switch_id and port_on_switch
But I don't see any code under. Shouldn't you write the code for the packets forwarding logic?
